# What does ‘Stubbed toes” mean in the sentence, “Curse words used to be reserved for “stubbed toes,”?

Tags: word-choice

I came across the sentence, “Curse words used to be reserved for private conversations or stubbed toes,” in the article in Education section of New York Times (February 1), titled “Have curse words become so common they have lost their shock value?”
The article begins with the following lines:

> “Curse words used to be reserved for private conversations or
>   ***stubbed toes***, but over the past few decades they seem to have solidly found their way into popular culture — into hit songs and
>   television shows, even book titles and company names.”

I know “stubbed toes” is an accidental but painful injury on the toe. 
Is it common to use ‘stubbed toes’ in psychological connotation in this way apart from physical injury accompanied with an acute pain that was my original perception?

P.S.

As I reflect my misinterpretation of “stubbed toes,” it might come from behavioral (or cultural) difference of expressions of pains used between Westerners and Japanese. When we Japanese stubbed toes, pricked hands, pinched fingers, stamped a nail, whatever, we don’t or seldom curse, though sometimes we blurt “Chikushou畜生 –God dam.” We simply shout “itai-痛い!” “Oh ite-e おお痛え!” meaning “Ouch.”

It didn’t come to my mind at first that “Stubbed toes” can be associated with swear words.

Comment: No, pretty sure it is meant literally only.

Comment: @tchist. Problem solved. I mistook ‘stubbed toes’ a metaphor of a stinging word directed to others. But seeing your comment and rereading the quote I found it means that curse is reserved for an utterance when you got stubbed toes. A naive mistake!

Comment: Cont.This question can be closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance, "stubbed toes" is not a metaphore. The idea is that well-spoken people only use curse words in private (for thoughtful emphasis) or when startled by something sudden and painful, like a stubbed toe. By and large, this is still true in the speach of Americans of a certain age. For example, my husband, who is a university professor might, in private, tell me that someone is "an asshole" though he would never say that in public. However, if he trips on the way out of Starbucks and spills his coffee all across the floor, he would say "shit!"

I'm of the view that what people say in public is a pretty good indicator of what they say in private. I think this is because it takes more self control to speak politely in public if your speech in private is dramatically different. We see that a lot when someone "slips" in public and is criticized for it. A recent example is the Super Bowl player who said he wouldn't want to share a locker room with a gay player, and the next day had to apologize with the strange statement the what he'd said "was what was in my mind but is not how I feel."

Comment: The Super Bowl player’s apology is interesting. I’d like to try this expression when I made a slip of tongue.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the usage in your excerpt is literal rather than metaphorical, I'll mention that stubbing one's toe is often regarded as the quintessential sudden-yet-minor painful injury.  I remember the Red Cross once ran radio ads for blood drives mentioning that donating blood "hurt less than the last time you stubbed your toe." Also, I managed to find an instance where someone used the phrase to explain someone's hypochondria ("He'd call his doctor, even if he stubbed his toe"). Ken Burns mentions that Lincoln once used the expression metaphorically when reacting to some bad news about the Civil War<sup>1</sup>:

> "Asked for his reaction to all this bad news, Lincoln said he felt like the boy who stubbed his toe — he was too big to cry, and it hurt too much to laugh."

Also, I managed to find a couple references where someone used the expression metaphorically. One was after Ronald Reagan performed poorly in a presidential debate<sup>2</sup>:

> The presidential motorcade rolled slowly and painfully out of Louisville this morning, its occupants well aware that the heavyweight debating champ had stubbed his toe on Walter Mondale.

and one where it was talking about an engineering problem<sup>3</sup>:

> Back in the 1930s, a Columbia University professor named Allan Nevins had already stubbed his toe on the problem.

So, even though it wasn't being used metaphorically in your quote, the phrase is in fact used metaphorically from time to time.

---

<sup>1</sup> *The Civil War: The complete text of the bestselling narrative history of the Civil War*, by Kenneth Burns, RICHARD BURNS, Geoffrey C. Ward.
<sup>2</sup> *Dirty Politics: Deception, Distraction, and Democracy* by Kathleen Hall Jamieson.
<sup>3</sup> *Plug It In, Switch It On: INSTANT* The Rotarian, May 1973.

Comment: It’s very informative comment. It seems my first impression – construing ‘stubbed toes” as a metaphor of stinging sb’s sentiment / heart wasn’t necessarily 100 per cent off the mark. It was good that I stopped short of deleting this question before reading your answer.